# Specify minimum Qt version for QtCreator / QMake build

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake, macos-mojave

I have a Qt project previously built using Qt 5.11.  In order to support MacOS Mojave's Dark Mode, I have updated the build to use Qt 5.13.2.  This works perfectly, but the kit version is stored locally in the session settings not with the .pro project file.

I wish to enforce a minimum Qt kit version for the build, so that the build will abort if the correct kit version is not selected, ideally in the .pro file rather then the source code.  How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe write something like `requires(QT_VERSION == xxxx)`?

Comment: @vahancho  :  I appreciate that is an RTFM kind of answer, but in my case the main development is done on Windows in Visual Studio using the Qt plug-in.  QtCreator and QMake are used only on the MacOS build and I really did not want to spend time becoming expert in something I really just want to crank the handle on.  However it looks like that is the solution - it would be great if you could post it as an answer rather then a comment so I can accept it and give credit.  Otherwise I'll post my own answer when I have it working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [versionAtLeast](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#versionatleast-variablename-versionnumber) or [lessThan](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#lessthan-variablename-value) you can check the Qt version. For instance:

```
equals(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5):lessThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 12) {
    message("Cannot use Qt $${QT_VERSION}")
    error("Use Qt 5.12 or newer")
}
```

or better:

```
!versionAtLeast(QT_VERSION, 5.12.0) {
    message("Cannot use Qt $${QT_VERSION}")
    error("Use Qt 5.12 or newer")
}
```

Comment: I feel may need to become more familiar with Qmake to deal with the deficiencies of QtCreator.  Looking at the documentation now, I can see solutions to other issues I have.  Thanks.